# Can't get eventListener to display value in console

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, console

Hey guys im new to javascript and trying to get a better understanding of it, i am trying to make a 8 ball project and currently just to see if it works get it to display in the console but all i recieve is that it is undefined

```js
const predictions = ['Ask again later, Better not tell you now, Cannot predict now, Concentrate and ask again'];
const btn = document.getElementById('btn')

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(predictions[randomNumber])
});




function randomNumber() {
    return Math.floor(math.random() * predictions.length)
};
```

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #06932d, #000000);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#prediction {
    position: fixed;
    top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href='8-ball.css'rel="stylesheet">
    <script defer src="8-ball.js"></script>
    <title>8 Ball</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="title">
        <h1>Try the Magic 8 Ball!</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="btn">
        <button>Try Me!</button>
    </div>

    <div id="prediction">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues in your code:

- You are missing the parenthesis to call `randomNumber` here:

  ```
  console.log(predictions[randomNumber()]);
  ```
- `Math` always starts with uppercase:

  ```
  return Math.floor(math.random() * predictions.length);
  ```
- It looks like you want `predictions` to be an array with multiple string elements. Instead, you have a single element with commas in it:

  ```
  const predictions = ['Ask again later, Better not tell you now, Cannot predict now, Concentrate and ask again'];
  ```

**With everything fixed:**

```js
function randomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * predictions.length);
}

const predictions = [
  'Ask again later.',
  'Better not tell you now.',
  'Cannot predict now.',
  'Concentrate and ask again.'
];

const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const prediction = document.getElementById('prediction');


btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  prediction.textContent = predictions[randomNumber()];
});
```

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #06932d, #000000);
  font-family: monospace;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#title {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0;
}

#box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#btn {
  border: 3px solid white;
  font-family: monospace;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 32px 0;
}

#prediction {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <h1 id="title">Try the Magic 8 Ball!</h1>
  <button id="btn">Try Me!</button>
  <p id="prediction">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```